# How to position labels with move command based on their center instead of left corner in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt

Hi I have several QLabels in a Qwidget. I am given a design that I need to create in Qt and it has only few labels actually. But one of labels' text my change. So text length is also changable. I used move() command it takes left corner point as reference point. I need to take center point of Label as reference point I guess.

```
class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 480
        self.height = 800
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)


        # Create widget
        main_page = QLabel(self)
        main_pixmap = QPixmap('main_page')
        main_page.setPixmap(main_pixmap)


        #logo
        logo = QLabel(self)
        logo_pixmap = QPixmap('logo')
        logo.setPixmap(logo_pixmap)
        logo.move(159,63)

        #Date
        today = format_date(datetime.datetime.now(),"dd MMMM", locale = 'tr').upper()
        day = format_date(datetime.datetime.now(), "EEEE", locale = 'tr').upper()
        date = QLabel(self)
        date.setText(day + " " + today )
        date.setFont(QFont("Lato", 24))
        date.setStyleSheet('color:white')
        self.move_to_center()

        #Clock
        clock = QLabel(self)
        clock.setText(strftime('%H:%M'))
        clock.setFont(QFont("Lato", 90))
        clock.setStyleSheet('color:white')
        clock.move(71,222)
```

How can I dynamicly put a label horizantally middle of a Qwidget?

Edit:
When I used layouts, labels lines up one after another as below
[image: You see what I Mean here. I want something like on the right one. But all the labels should be centered horizantally]

Comment: With "dynamically" you mean that the label's text may change at some point once the program has already started? Is there a specific reason for not using layouts?

Comment: Yes @musicamante , Labels are going to represent day and username so their text's will change. There no reason for not using layouts. I just need to recreate exact design that I am given. For that, I thought I should use coordinates(with `move()` function.)

Comment: There are different ways of recreate an "exact design" (expecially in this era of "responsive" designs). While recreating the exact designed might be ok on your computer, it might not on another, expecially if the user has different default font or DPI settings. Also, you're not setting a fixed size but only a geometry, leaving the possibility of resizing (by the user or even the system, if required) which will obviously make everything ugly. Is the "exact design" really mandatory or you just used because you couldn't achieve it with layouts? Because it's completely doable with them.

Comment: @musicamante it is a kiosk application for a card reader. So there will be no user actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with centering widgets is that they can alter their size according to their contents.

The simpler solution for your case is to create a label that has a fixed width and has its text center aligned:

```
        clock = QLabel(self)
        clock.setText(strftime('%H:%M'))
        clock.setFixedWidth(self.width())
        clock.move(0, 222)
        clock.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
```

While this is fine, there is a couple of problems:

- if the label has more than one line and you don't want it to span over the whole width, the alignment will always be centered (which can be ugly);
- if the original text is on one line and the new text has more, it won't be updated properly (unless you call `label.adjustSize()` after every text change)

Another solution is to create a subclass of QLabel that automatically repositions itself as soon as it's shown or the text is changed:

```
class CenterLabel(QLabel):
    vPos = 0
    def setText(self, text):
        super(CenterLabel, self).setText(text)
        if self.parent():
            self.center()

    def setVPos(self, y):
        # set a vertical reference point
        self.vPos = y
        if self.parent():
            self.center()

    def center(self):
        # since there's no layout, adjustSize() allows us to update the
        # sizeHint based on the text contents; we cannot use the standard
        # size() as it's unreliable when there's no layout
        self.adjustSize()
        x = (self.parent().width() - self.sizeHint().width()) / 2
        self.move(x, self.vPos)
```

That said, I still think that using a layout is a better and simpler solution. You just have to create the "background" pixmap with the main widget as a parent and without adding it to the layout, then set the layout and add everything else using `layout.addSpacing` for the vertical spacings between all widgets.

The only issue here is that if a label text changes its line count, all subsequent widgets will be moved accordingly. If that's the case, just set a fixed height for the widget which will be equal to the distance between the top of the widget and the top of the next, then add the widget to the layout ensuring that it is horizontally centered and top aligned.

```
    def initUI(self):
        #self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self._width, self._height)

        self.background = QLabel(self)
        self.background.setPixmap(QPixmap('background.png'))

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        # set spacing between items to 0 to ensure that there are no added margins
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        # add a vertical spacing for the top margin;
        # I'm just using random values
        layout.addSpacing(20)

        main_page = QLabel(self)
        main_pixmap = QPixmap('main_page')
        main_page.setPixmap(main_pixmap)
        # add the widget ensuring that it's horizontally centered
        layout.addWidget(main_page, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

        #logo
        logo = QLabel(self)
        logo_pixmap = QPixmap('logo')
        logo.setPixmap(logo_pixmap)
        layout.addWidget(logo, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

        layout.addSpacing(50)

        #Date
        today = format_date(datetime.datetime.now(),"dd MMMM", locale = 'tr').upper()
        day = format_date(datetime.datetime.now(), "EEEE", locale = 'tr').upper()
        date = QLabel(self)
        date.setText(day + " " + today )
        date.setFont(QFont("Lato", 24))
        date.setStyleSheet('color:white')
        # set a fixed height equal to the vertical position of the next label
        date.setFixedHeight(100)
        # ensure that the label is always on top of its layout "slot"
        layout.addWidget(date, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignTop)

        #Clock
        clock = QLabel(self)
        clock.setText(strftime('%H:%M'))
        clock.setFont(QFont("Lato", 90))
        clock.setStyleSheet('color:white')
        layout.addWidget(clock, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignTop)

        # add a bottom "stretch" to avoid vertical expanding of widgets
        layout.addStretch(1000)
```